# Ansible: register content not available for other host

Tags: ansible

Below is a part of a playbook in Ansible 2.1:

```
- hosts: localhost
   any_errors_fatal: true
   tasks:
    - name: Bla Bla
      file: path=/var/tmp/somedir state=directory
      #ignore_errors: no
    - name: Create directory for every host
      file: path=/var/tmp/somedir/{{ item }} state=directory
      with_items: "{{ groups['XYZ'] }}"
    - name: Get File contents of NewFile
      shell: cat NewFile.txt executable=/bin/bash
      register: file_contents
 - hosts: XYZ
  #any_errors_fatal: true
   vars:
    num_hosts: "{{ groups['XYZ'] | length }}"
    serial: num_hosts
  tasks:
    - name: Copy files to corresponding directories
      vars:
         path: /var/tmp/somedir/{{ item[0] }}
      synchronize: mode=pull src={{ item[1] }} dest={{ path }}
      with_nested:
           - "{{ groups['XYZ'] }}"
           - with_lines: cat NewFile.txt
```

This does not work.
Now the problem is i am not able to reference `file_contents` which has been registered under localhost and Ansible is not supporting to `cat` the `NewFile` from the `hosts: XYZ`

Is there any way to do this in some simple manner? I need to check contents of the `NewFile` in this playbook only and then use the same to copy files from remote to local.

Comment: did you try set_fact, if not just try to assign the value of the file_contents to some variable by using set_fact then it will be available throughout the playbook.

Comment: i tried `set_fact` setting the value of '`file_contents` to a variable `lines` and then used the same variable in:

`with_nested:

           - "{{ groups['XYZ'] }}"

           - with_items: lines`

I get the below error:
`link_stat \"/home/XYZ/with_items\" failed: No such file or directory`

Comment: use the debug module and check the value of the lines

Comment: `set_fact` are on a per host basis as far as I know. With the second loop in  `with_nested` ansible takes "with_items" as its input, like below:
`TASK [Copy Log files to corresponding node directories] ************************
failed: [host-ip] (item=[u'host-ip', u'with_items']) => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh  -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' \"user@host-ip:with_items\" \"/var/tmp/somedir/host-ip\"",`

Comment: you didn't past the value of the `lines` variable, paste it, then we can suggest you more.

Comment: Value of `lines` variable is the path on remote hosts from which files are to be copied, like, 
/home/user/somedir/myflder
/usr/bin/start/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, facts (or all variables) are stored on a host basis. If you have registered a values from a task running on *localhost*, you can access it from any task running in context of other hosts through the global `hostvars` dict. All hosts and their facts are stored in there:

```
hostvars['localhost']['file_contents']
```

<sub>I am not entirely sure simply *registered* variables are available in the hostvars dict. If not, you have to use `set_fact` in the first play to store it as a fact.</sub>

Comment: you want me to use something like this,
`tasks:
    - name: Copy Log files to corresponding node directories
      vars:
         path: /var/tmp/somedir/{{ item[0] }}
     #shell: scp -pr ogw@{{ item[0] }}:{{ item[1] }} {{ path }} executable=/bin/bash
      synchronize: mode=pull src={{ item[1] }} dest={{ path }}
      with_nested:
           - "{{ groups['XYZ'] }}"
           - with_items: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['file_contents'] }}"`
Even the above is giving me error on `with_items`. No values are stored in `with_items`